# Optimize Mysql Query while joining same table multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Can anybody help me optimize this mysql query?
The query is taking more than 1 min to fetch 1000 rows of data. 
The sub query with FIND_IN_SET(id,GROUP_CONCAT(t.id))!=0 in the select statement is taking too much time to fetch data.
```

Also can you please provide the tips that can be used to optimize query where we have to join same table multiple times.
The query is mentioned below:

```
   SELECT mem.id,
    CASE 
    WHEN t.due_date IS NOT NULL THEN
    (SELECT description FROM descriptionTable WHERE CODE=
    (SELECT task_type FROM memberTask WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,GROUP_CONCAT(t.id))!=0 AND due_date=MIN(t.due_date) LIMIT 1))
    ELSE
    (SELECT description FROM descriptionTable WHERE CODE=
    (SELECT task_type FROM memberTask WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,GROUP_CONCAT(t1.id))!=0 AND due_date=MIN(t1.due_date) LIMIT 1))
    END AS task_type
    FROM member mem
    INNER JOIN memberProgram p ON mem.id=p.member_id
    LEFT JOIN memberTask t ON t.program=p.prog_name AND t.member_id=p.member_id AND t.status=1
    LEFT JOIN memberTask t1 ON t1.member_id=p.member_id AND t1.status=1 AND t1.program IS NULL 
    GROUP BY mem.id
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Can you describe in words, what the query is supposed to do? You want a certain description per member, as can easily be seen. A member can have many programs, and a program can have many tasks, and a task can have many descriptions. But tasks are not always related to a program. So we can say that a member has program tasks and non-program tasks. And of these you seem to want one single task-related description per member. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, as you said: A member can have many programs, and a program can have many tasks. Here we have to select the taskType from the memberTask table which furthur joins with the descriptionTable to get the full description. The main problem here is the time taken to get the taskType as we have to check if the task if program task or non-program task with respect to min due_date field  of memberTask table.

Comment: So from a member's tasks you want the task with the minimum due date and for this task one of its descriptions, no matter which?

Comment: Yes. I want task_Type field of that member from memberTask table checking condition whether it is programTask or nonProgramTask no matter which as the above mentioned code has already used limit 1 while fetching the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are using the query will increase the complexity of the query execution and it will have to go through lots of cross-joined rows to pull the required rows. The better solution will first pull the required rows from the target table: memberTask, and after that join that to the main query.

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CASE WHEN t1.program IS NOT NULL THEN t1.id ELSE NULL END,'')),',','') AS first_dueDate,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CASE WHEN t1.program IS NOT NULL THEN 'first' ELSE 'second' END,'')),',','') AS selectFlag,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CASE WHEN t1.program IS NULL THEN t1.id ELSE NULL END,'')),',','') AS first_dueDate,
aa.member_id FROM memberTask t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT due_date,program,aa.member_id,MAX(tsk.id) AS selId FROM memberTask tsk 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT t.member_id,t.program,t.task_type,MIN(due_date) AS seldate FROM memberTask t WHERE tsk.status=1 
GROUP BY t.member_id,IFNULL(t.program,''))aa 
ON tsk.member_id=aa.member_id AND IFNULL(tsk.program,'')=IFNULL(aa.program,'') AND tsk.due_date=aa.seldate 
GROUP BY due_date,program,aa.member_id) bb ON t1.id=bb.selId GROUP BY t1.member_id,t1.program
```

The breakdown of the query goes as follows:

```
SELECT t.member_id,t.program,t.task_type,MIN(due_date) AS seldate FROM memberTask t WHERE tsk.status=1 
GROUP BY t.member_id,IFNULL(t.program,'')
```

This is the inner most query which will pull the records based on memberid and its programs selecting min due date.

```
SELECT due_date,program,aa.member_id,MAX(tsk.id) AS selId FROM memberTask tsk 
INNER JOIN (Inner Most Query)aa 
ON tsk.member_id=aa.member_id AND IFNULL(tsk.program,'')=IFNULL(aa.program,'') AND tsk.due_date=aa.seldate 
GROUP BY due_date,program,aa.member_id
```

this query will pull the max id among the rows with same due date

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CASE WHEN t1.program IS NOT NULL THEN t1.id ELSE NULL END,'')),',','') AS first_dueDate,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CASE WHEN t1.program IS NOT NULL THEN 'first' ELSE 'second' END,'')),',','') AS selectFlag,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CASE WHEN t1.program IS NULL THEN t1.id ELSE NULL END,'')),',','') AS first_dueDate,
aa.member_id FROM memberTask t1
INNER JOIN (second query) bb ON t1.id=bb.selId GROUP BY t1.member_id,t1.program
```

This will pull whole the multiple rowed data to single row.

Now while joining this selected data to main query you should use following cases.

```
SELECT * FROM member mem
INNER JOIN program pro om mem.id=pro.member_id
LEFT JOIN tmpTable tl ON t1.member_id=mem.member_id AND
CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(pro.`prog_name`, t1.prog_relate_task) THEN t1.program=pro.program AND t1.selectFlag='first'
ELSE t1.selectFlag='second' END
```

These are the general understanding of your case. You can change the pull records according to your requirement

let me know if it works or not?

Comment: Thanks for the query. The last block of the query:
CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(pro.`prog_name`, t1.prog_relate_task) THEN t1.program=pro.program AND t1.selectFlag='first'
ELSE t1.selectFlag='second' END
is what i was waiting for.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if I understand completely what the query is supposed to do. What I understand is this: For each member get the task (no matter whether program-related or not) with the minimun due date and for this get the description for the task type.

So: select members and get the description in a subquery with `LIMIT`:

```
select
  m.id,
  (
    select d.description
    from membertask t
    join descriptiontable d on d.code = t.task_type
    where t.member_id = m.id
    order by t.due_date
    limit 1
  ) as description
from member;
```

Comment: Here, we are missing the main issue, to check whether the task is of program type or none program type. i.e. if task table has program then the duedate must be of that tasktable otherwise the duedate must be of the nonprogram data of tasktable.

Comment: I don't understand. A task has a due date. A task can be related to a program or not. I am selecting the oldest task, no matter whether program-related or not. How do you want this different? Do you want to prefer program-related tasks over non-program-related ones or vice versa?